# Check that scroll is on the area of child

Tags: javascript, css

So my problem is that i have a container with elements inside. Container have a scroll. Thing i wan't to know is there is any possibility to check that scroll matches height of specyfic child element in context of a container. I tried to make calculation based on getBoundingClientRect but I have no idea how to calculate this.

[image]

In this picture scroll matches into height of the child so function should return true.

Comment: You can use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. With this you can react whenever an element comes into view.

Comment: But i don't want to know when this element comes into view but when scrolls hit height of that element.

Comment: What do you mean then with scroll his height of element? Scroll can't hit any height since it only scrolls and depends on viewport size.